# How to write AuthorizeAttribute if a role contains space

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, authorization

I am using MVC3/4. But it is just a general question in authorization.

One of the role I have is named "Trip Leader" in the database, which contains a space.

I tried `[Authorize(Roles="'Trip Leader', Administrator")]` but it failed to work. Can anyone help?

Comment: Try making a constant whose value is "Trip Leader"?

Comment: How to? `[Authorize(Roles=TripLeader,"Administrator")]`? It won't work.

Comment: @Blaise Have you managed to do this?

Comment: No. I have used `Trip_Leader` instead of `Trip Leader`. Easy fix is no fix at all. And I removed the ugly underscore when displaying roles to the user.

Comment: Looking at the AuthorizeAttribute, it splits the Users and Roles strings using a comma. I'm facing a problem also, but I don't understand if it just splits using a comma, why is there a problem???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own attribute and derive from AuthorizeAttribute. Then override the AuthorizeCore method and implement your own logic with validation on a role that contains a space.

An example could be something like this:

```
    public class CustomAuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
       private readonly IUserRoleService _userRoleService;
       private string[] _allowedRoles;
    
       public CustomAuthAttribute(params string[] roles)
       {
          _userRoleService = new UserRoleService();
          _allowedRoles = roles;
       }
       protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
       {
        //something like this.
        var userName = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        var userRoles = _userRoleService .GetUserRoles(userName); // return list of strings
        return _allowedRoles.Any(x => userRoles.Contains(x));
       }
   }
```

**Usage**

```
[CustomAuth("role withspace","admin")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[Authorize(Roles="Trip Leader")]
[Authorize(Roles="Administrator")]
```

EDIT: The above code requires the user to fulfill both roles. If you are looking for an either/or authorization, try this:

```
[Authorize(Roles="Trip Leader, Administrator")]
```

Comment: It doesn't appear that you can put multiple Authorize attributes on the same class or function. You can have different ones on the class and the function that seem to form an AND while the comma forms an OR.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the other answers to work. My roles had commas in them and wouldn't work with the original AuthorizeAttribute.

```
   //Custom Authorize class that derives from the existing AuthorizeAttribute
    public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {

        private string[] _allowedRoles;

        public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(params string[] roles)
        {
            //allowed roles
            _allowedRoles = roles;
        }
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            var roleManager = httpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationUserManager>();
            //Grab all of the Roles for the current user
            var roles = roleManager.GetRoles(httpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId());
            //Determine if they are currently in any of the required roles (and allow / disallow accordingly) 
            return _allowedRoles.Any(x => roles.Contains(x));
        }
    }
```