# Can't make AuthorizeAttribute work, if role name contains spaces

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, authorization

While working over a windows domain intranet site (with `<authentication mode="Windows" />`) I came across the following problem:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Domain Users, Domain Admins")]
public class MyController: Controller {...}
```

This controller is not available for any user because of the spaces in the names of the active directory groups. So can I make MVC (or ASP.Net) authorize correctly, while using role names (here: names of AD groups) with spaces?

Just similar questions with no respond:

1. [AD Groups with spaces used for roles authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611313/ad-groups-with-spaces-used-for-roles-authorization).
2. [How to write AuthorizeAttribute if a role contains space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954907/how-to-write-authorizeattribute-if-a-role-contains-space)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create your own attribute and derive from AuthorizeAttribute. Then override the AuthorizeCore method and implement your own logic with validation on a role that contains a space.

An example could be something like this:

```
public class CustomAuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
   private readonly IUserRoleService _userRoleService;
   private string[] _allowedRoles;

   public CustomAuthAttribute(params string[] roles)
   {
      _userRoleService = new UserRoleService();
      _allowedRoles = roles;
   }
   protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   {
    //something like this.
    var userName = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;
    var userRoles = _userRoleService .GetUserRoles(userName); // return list of strings
    return _allowedRoles.Any(x => userRoles.Contains(x));
   }
```

}

**Usage**

```
[CustomAuth("role withspace","admin")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
}
```

Comment: I'd say, writing security code is pretty dangerous, isn't it?

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov well no, since you derive from AuthorizeAttribute you will still benefit from the features built in to the AuthorizeAttribute.

Comment: How do you inject UserRoleService?

Comment: You can use any DI container for this, like autofac, ninject, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can try adding "MyDomain\" in front of your names.

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"mydomain\Domain Users, mydomain\Domain Admins")]
```

Remember to add the @ or double up the slashes "\".

Answer (score 3):

Roles containing a space character worked fine when I tried the following:

```
public static class AppRoles
{
    public const string Manager = @"domain\App Manager";
    public const string Admin = @"domain\App Admin";
}
    
[Authorize(Roles = AppRoles.Admin)] 
public class MyAbcController : Controller
{
    // Code
}
```